typo3 permissions issue
Since yesterday (nothing was changed) I Got the following error when I want to edit a page or add content.

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.


I'm logged in as backend admin with full rights ... any hint for me?
The access rights looks fine.

Thanks in advance.
php log messages
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /mnt/web107/a3/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Renderer/Default/CellRenderer.php on line 158: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/index.php
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /mnt/web107/a3/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Renderer/Default/CellRenderer.php on line 158: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/index.php
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/.git
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/fileadmin/src
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /mnt/web107/a3/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Renderer/Default/CellRenderer.php on line 158: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/index.php
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /mnt/web107/a3/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Renderer/Default/CellRenderer.php on line 158: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/index.php
AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  Only variables can be passed by reference in /mnt/web107/a3/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Renderer/Default/CellRenderer.php on line 158: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/index.php
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/67/90/58486790/htdocs/typo3_grau_01/.git


If your site is hosted at STR***O, you are possibly affected by a configuration change done by the hosting company. A number of users have reported this issue recently (mid July 204).

Please keep in mind that Typo3 v6.2 (which you're using according to the tags) is EOL since years

@Michael what kind of configruation change? and yes thats my hoster.

@NicoHaase sorry wrong clicked... I use 7.6 ... thats not that better ;) I will migrate soon

Also, please share more details, like the code involved, and the raw error message you're facing. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is a site for programming-related topics, and not for support questions

@NicoHaase thats the most precise error message I have. There is nothing better.

Nothing in the server log? Nothing when you use a higher level of error reporting?

@NicoHaase added some php error log messages

https://forum.t3academy.de/d/507-create-content-element-forbidden-error-403

there is no solution right? only to moove to a better hosting company right?
Then I try to move it to one of my linux servers

You still haven't shared any of the code involved. Is this problem even related about programming? Did you write any code on your own?

its an typo3 issue.

Nope, it's not a TYPO3 problem, but a problem of Strato. Do some research, and you'll find similar issues in other projects (eg Contao) - what they always have in common is that they are hosted by Strato and the problems have "suddenly" appeared without code change this week.

You are showing your path of the server, I don't think that is supposed to be shown.
Is it?

Can you please check your involved .htaccess files whether there is a RedirectRule directive that contains a ? in the substitution part (right part)?
similar to something like this: RewriteRule .* foo.php?bla
By default, TYPO3 does not ship such rules, so it could be a custom one.

We contacted STR***O and received the following response:
‘You had contacted us because you encountered an error message (‘403 Forbidden’) when using your Typo3 instance.
This is due to the fact that an insecure vulnerability was closed by a software update in the infrastructure. This would have allowed attackers to penetrate your web space and execute malicious code. This prevents the communication of Typo3 and its used method with the web server in some areas of the Typo3 instance.
We refer to vulnerability description CVE-2024-38474 (https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2024-38474). This update will generally be installed on all current Apache instances.
For security reasons, we will not release the insecure method used by Typo3 on the host systems. We kindly ask you to contact the developer of Typo3 and inform him about the vulnerability. We expressly recommend that you do not implement any modifications that circumvent this, as this will make you vulnerable. ’

Please also share how to resolve the initial problem. Strato stating that they won't provide any help is not a good solution

It turned out that this seems to be a global filter on Strato sites, that is blocking any URL which contains %3f. It is not related to TYPO3, and not the result of any "insecure method used by Typo3"... → see https://forge.typo3.org/issues/104410
